# Why does the memory space show different value than the variable type occupies?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
  #include <stdlib.h> 
  #include <stdio.h>

    struct  Edge
 {
 // for every edge u,v,w
int u;
int v;
int w;
};

  struct Graph
 {
  // for graph vertex v edge e
int V;
int E;  
struct Edge *edge;
 };

  int main()
  {

     int i,j,k,w,s;
// open memory for graph g 
struct Graph *g = (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
 //expected 20 but it show me 16
printf("%d",sizeof(struct Graph));

   return 0;
```

}

*int requirement 4 byte two integer=8byte+struct Edge *edge(4+4+4=12), 12+8=20 byte but sizeof(struct Graph) show me 16 why?  *

Comment: `edge` has the type `Edge*` so it just stores an address. So on your system the address is either 8 bytes long or 4 bytes and the compiler pads the memory layout so that it is aligned

Comment: thank you,ı understood

Comment: First if you are thinking in bytes when using a C `struct` you do something wrong. Typically there is *alignment* that may create "gaps" between the struct members. Also don't rely on `sizeof(int)` being 4 or `sizeof(void *)` being 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`edge` has type "*pointer to* `struct Edge`" (`struct Edge *`) - it stores the address of a `struct Edge` object.  If you get `16` for the size of a `struct Graph`, that means pointers on your system are 4 bytes wide.

Most systems have alignment requirements such that multi-byte objects start on addresses that are multiples of 2 or 4 (or even larger values).  To maintain these alignment restrictions, `struct` types may have "padding" bytes between members, so the size of a `struct` may be larger than the sum of the sizes of its members.